# Is there a way to Move GameObject from point a to b and b to a using Rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am moving a Gameobject from one point to another point. using a rigid body, I am moving a game object from one point to another point using this code. but is not the right way, because I have to stop the object sometimes. and this code does not let that happen. I am using Time. time to move on.

```
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    pusherinitPos = transform.position;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!stopMove)
    {
        float timeSin = Mathf.Sin(Time.time) / divider;
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(pusherinitPos.x, pusherinitPos.y, 
        pusherinitPos.z + timeSin);
        rb.MovePosition(newPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to use more self-explanatory titles ;) `Is there a way` -> Yes! ... but I'm sure that's not the answer you are targeting ;) Is something not working/bhaving as expected with your current code?

Comment: my code is running perfectly with Time. time. but when I change the variable to stopmove to false and again back to true the gamobject makes jerks and push the other gameobject infront of it

Answer (score 1):

[`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) of course continues to run while your object is stopped.

You could rather use

```c#
// store your own passed time
private float _time;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    pusherinitPos = transform.position;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (stopMove) return;

    var timeSin = Mathf.Sin(_time) / divider;
    var newPos = pusherinitPos + Vector3.forward * timeSin;
    rb.MovePosition(newPos);

    // increase by the time passed since last frame
    // see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html
    _time += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Sure. I'll use and check it whether it works or not